# How to add comment to a column in a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, metadata

I'm new to Postgres. I would like add a comment to my column `mod` in a table called `app-user-bookings`

I have tried this sql code:

```
alter table app_user_bookings
modify column mod 
int default 1 
comment "1# mobile booking,    2# admin booking,    3# web booking, 4# tell call";
```

But which didn't help me, can anyone help me?

Comment: For the record, here is the [comment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) section of the documentation

Comment: You should also add a check constraint that makes sure the column does not store any other value then mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've incorporated your suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To update comment, don't use alter command.

Here is the [PostgreSQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html):

```
comment on column app_user_bookings.mod is '1# mobile booking,    2# admin booking,    3# web booking, 4# tell call'
```

It makes sense to add a check to prevent wrong values appearing:

```
ALTER TABLE app_user_bookings
ADD CHECK (mod IN (1,2,3,4));
```