# Is it possible to create a comment for a table in postgres? If not - how is a table typically documented in a similar manner to columns

Tags: postgresql, documentation

It's possible to have documentation of a particular column within a postgres table, as it outlined here: [How to add comment to a column in a table in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160667/how-to-add-comment-to-a-column-in-a-table-in-postgres)

I'm not sure how to create a comment for a particular table though, and am interested in doing so *on* the database (rather than in confluence or something similar).

The only thing that I can think of is to create an additional table `documentation__tables`, or something similar, and with columns such as

```
table_name  |  description
--------------------------
...         | ...
```

Where `table_name` would match the name of the table from the schema.

I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic approach than this, or if there's a typical approach to documenting a table of the database within the database itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) `comment on` can also be used for tables:

```
comment on table table_name is 'Some interesting comment';
```

Comment: Thank you, I did google and obviously failed pretty hard... I must have been googling _around_ the documentation some how.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of.  If you want it within the database, you would want to create a documentation table.  Maybe a column for tablename, date, and a field for the notes you take on it.

Comment: Thanks - I struggled to find much in the way of existing workflows around this, and what was typically documented.

Comment: This is wrong. You can attach comments to tables using `comment on` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html